# Using Oracle DB exporter with Prometheus

Tags: oracle, prometheus, exporter

Trying to scrape oracle db using Oracle DB exporter mentioned on Prometheus website

exporter:
[OracleDB Exporter](https://github.com/iamseth/oracledb_exporter)

But cannot understand how to connect this to a remote oracle DB instance.
It specifies to create DATA_SOURCE_NAME but nothing is mentioned regarding connection properties like username and password, need help regarding this

tried running docker for the exporter

```
 docker run --name oracledb_exporter -p 9161:9161 -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME=system/oracle@hostname/xe iamseth/oracledb_exporter
time="2019-11-28T05:08:29Z" level=info msg="Starting oracledb_exporter 0.2.3" source="main.go:337" 
time="2019-11-28T05:08:29Z" level=error msg="Error pinging oracle: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor\n" source="main.go:168" 
time="2019-11-28T05:08:29Z" level=info msg="Try to reconnect..." source="main.go:173" 
time="2019-11-28T05:08:29Z" level=error msg="Unable to connect to oracle:ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor\n" source="main.go:181" 
time="2019-11-28T05:08:29Z" level=info msg="Listening on :9161" source="main.go:359"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Switched to InfluxDB with Logstash, it had already existing plugin for data exports.**

InfluxDB is also a time series database, Logstash had already existing plugin for running queries on database and then submitting data to influxDB, used scheduler in Logstash to scrape data in intervals

[influxdb output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-influxdb.html)

Used Grafana for dashboards which supports prometheus as well as influxDB.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `env` parameter to set the database connection string while running the Oracle database exporter Docker container.

E.g.:

1. Create a file named as `env` and define the following as below:

   ```
   DATA_SOURCE_NAME=SYS/Oradoc_db1@192.168.0.45:1521/ORCLCDB
   ```
2. ```
   docker run -d --name --link oracle oracledb_custom_exporter -p 9161:9161 --env-file env <image_id_of_oracledb_exporter>
   ```

Comment: Is creating an env file necessary for the single value? Could this be set directly `--env=DATA_SOURCE_NAME="SYS/Oradoc_db1@192.168.0.45:1521/ORCLCDB"`?